# Unable to publish Django project to Azure Web App from VS2015

Tags: python, django, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I've written a Django project in Visual Studio 2015 which runs successfully on a local server when debugging via the IDE. However, when I...

1. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select **Publish**
2. Select `Microsoft Azure Web Apps` as the publish target
3. Click **New...** and enter details to create a new web app on Azure:

   - creating a new `App Service Plan` with the same name as the Web App
   - creating a new `Resource Group` with the same name as the Web App
   - `Region`: North Europe
   - `Database server`: No database
4. Click **Create**
5. Select Publish method: `Web Deploy` and successfully **Validate Connection** to new Azure Web App
6. Click **Publish**

...the Output window shows that the Publish failed:

```
------ Publish started: Project: RaceLogger, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Deploy package/publish related properties...
Gather all files from Project items @(Content). Adding:
app\templates\app\performance_form.html;app\templates\auth\login.html;app\templates\index.html;app\templates\layout.html;app\templates\app\performance_detail.html;app\templates\app\performance_list.html;requirements.txt
Gather all files from Project output (IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath). Adding:
Gather all files from Project items @(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths,ReferenceComWrappersToCopyLocal,ResolvedIsolatedComModules,_DeploymentLooseManifestFile,NativeReferenceFile).
Gather all files from Project items @(AllExtraReferenceFiles). Adding:
Gather all files from Project items @(_binDeployableAssemblies). Adding:
DjangoStaticUrlSetting=/static/
Regenerating web.config
Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Python Tools\web_config.xml" to "obj\Debug\web.config".
Updating app settings in web.config
Made 1 replacement(s).
Updating rewrite conditions in web.config
Made 1 replacement(s).
Updating FastCGI handlers in web.config
Made 1 replacement(s).
Copying file from "obj\Debug\web.config" to "C:\Users\username\Documents\Files\Web_Projects\django\RaceLoggerProject\RaceLogger\web.config".
Regenerating web.debug.config
Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Python Tools\web_debug_config.xml" to "obj\Debug\web.debug.config".
Updating ptvsd secret in web.debug.config
Made 1 replacement(s).
Copying file from "obj\Debug\web.debug.config" to "C:\Users\username\Documents\Files\Web_Projects\django\RaceLoggerProject\RaceLogger\web.debug.config".

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've checked that the newly created Azure Web App is running via the Azure Management Portal and have modified the Web App's `Application settings` so that Python version 3.4 is selected (in my local environment I'm running Python 3.4.4 and Django 1.9.3) to no avail. I've tried updating to VS2015 Update 2 RC, but this makes no difference either.

I've also tried creating the sample `Django Web Project` available in the New Project window of VS2015 in a Python 3.4.4 / Django 1.9.4 virtual environment and that fails to publish in exactly the same way.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to successfully publish a Django project to an Azure Web App from VS2015?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I created the sample Django Web Project in Visual studio as per your steps. Added a virtual environment (Python 3.4, Django 1.9.4). And it published to Azure Web apps without any error. May I know which Python version did you use in Virtual environment?

Comment: Hi Gandhali, when I created the sample Django Web Project, I used a Python 3.4.4 / Django 1.9.4 virtual environment.

Comment: @w5m,I tried to reproduce this issue following these steps:
1. Create the Django project and add the virtual environment named **'env'**.
2. Regenerate the requirement.txt file after I installed all dependences. 
3.deploy the site using VS and follow your description and the website works. Could you please following the document :https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/ or you can use the GitHub to deploy your site (http://blog.smarx.com/posts/tutorial-running-a-python-web-application-in-windows-azure)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use virtual environment to specify your python version, which will not be limited by Python versions on Azure Web Apps Service.

**Right** click the **Python Environments** section under the solution, click the **Add Virtual Environment**.

[image]

Select the python version, mark *Download and install packages*, click **Create** button to create a new virtual enviroment under your solution directory.
[image]

Press F5 to debug for testing the application, then try to deploy to Azure again.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gary. Unfortunately, I had already created virtual environments (in the way you've described) for the two examples above. Am I right in understanding that the Azure Web App Service's Python version setting is irrelevant (i.e. it could even be set to OFF?) if I've deployed a virtual environment to Azure?

Comment: Yes, your python application will use the virtual environment, but if you need run any python commands on Kudu Console site or VSO or deployment tasks, it will leverage the python environment on azure.